# Get cross data of multiple tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I got the task to find the cluster number of a customer, based on where he is living.

For example:

1. Customer Table - Teststraße 16
2. Address Table - Look for Teststraße with number 16
3. Give back the cluster ID of Teststraße
4. And if it´s possible get back the number of the cluster ID from the Cluster-Table

Table Address:

[image: address]

Table Cluster:

[image: cluster]

Table Customer:

[image: customer]

I hope everything was understandable to you.

I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can look in the address table directly and join it with the cluster table:

```
SELECT c.number
FROM address AS a
INNER JOIN cluster AS c
ON a.cluster = c.id
WHERE a.street = 'Teststraße'
   AND a.street_number = 16
```

if you want to have the information about all customers, join it with this table as well and remove the where clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM customer
INNER JOIN address
ON customer.street = address.street
   AND customer.street_number = address.street_number
INNER JOIN cluster
ON address.cluster = cluster.id
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast feedback! Sounds good! The problem is, I have to get the cluster ID´s of all streets in the customer table, not only from 1. Thanks for your feedback again!

Comment: in your customer table is no column with the clusterId

Comment: @pascallammers: i added an additional sql statement, which joins the customer table too

Comment: Thank you very much! It now gives me data with the cluster ID but some data is showing double and I don´t know why :)

Comment: @pascallammers: do you mean, some rows where shown multiple times, or some columns? if it shows you the rows multiple times, it's possible your customer table has some rows double. if it shows you some columns multiple times, simply define in the select which you want to be shown

Comment: I used DISTINCT and specific column names to get rid of the duplicate entries :) Thanks for you quick help :)